# Mongoose join 3 collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, join

this is the code to join 2 collections in mongodb :

```
    Employee.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          nameAR: name,
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "salaries",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "employeeId",
          as: "report",
        },
      },
    ])
```

i want to join another collection `vacation` also on `employeeId` ( join 3 collections ), how to do that ?

Comment: Another `"$lookup"`?

Comment: i tried but it will just ignore the first one.. anyway, i solved it without the need for a third join

Comment: Perhaps you were overwriting `"report"` with your second `"$lookup"`?

Comment: no, it was completely another ```$lookup``` : ```$lookup: {from: "vacations", localField: "_id", foreignField: "employeeId", as: "vacations", }```

Comment: There must have been some other issue then.  You can do as many `"$lookup"` as you want.

Comment: thank you, i will come back to this question when i need it